# Почему не удается проверить скриптом домены на занятость?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Я использую bash на Ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash

for letter1 in {g,o}; do
    for letter2 in {a..z}; do
        for letter3 in {a..z}; do
            name="$letter1$letter2$letter3.ru"
            found=$(whois $name | grep domain | awk {'print $2'})
            if [ -n "$found" ]
            then
                echo "имя $name занято"
            else
                echo "имя $name свободно" 
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Через какое-то время все домены начинают определяться как свободные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `whois` имеет ограничение на количество допустимых запросов в единицу времени. Если добавить во внутренний цикл задержку, то скрипт должен отрабатывать верно, хотя и медленно.